# how to remove all occurances of a node in an edges in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have an edge_index and want to remove one element `n = 3` of it

```
edges = torch.tensor([
    [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
    [1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2]])




nodes = torch.unique(edges)
n = nodes[-1]  # I want to remove this from edge_index
```

I tried this but it's not working

```
arr = edges[~(edges == [n]).all(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code to

```py
arr = edges[(~(edges == n)).all(axis=0).unsqueeze(0).repeat(edges.shape[0], 1)].reshape(edges.shape[0], -1)
```

Comment: can you explain why you used axis=0 and not axis=1?

Comment: The shape is `[2, 6]`. It need to aggregate over the first axis (`axis=0`) to get `[6]`. Then get the dimension back using `unsqueeze`, and `repeat`. Now we have bool of shape `[2, 6]`. Use this for boolean selection, which will convert to `[-1]`. To restore the original shape use `reshape(edges.shape[0], -1)`

Comment: I get it, thank you.  again which one will convert it to [-1]?

Comment: `[-1]` here mean that it is a flat array. It happen after boolean indexing. If you remove the final `reshape` part, and print its shape. It will be one dimensional (flat) array